# Kong - custom plugins returning: custom-plugin plugin is enabled but not installed;

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kong

I have an instance of Kong that I am running using Dockerfile with contents:

```
FROM kong:1.4.0

WORKDIR /files
COPY plugins kong/plugins
ENV KONG_LOG_LEVEL=debug
ENV KONG_PLUGINS custom-plugin
ENV KONG_LUA_PACKAGE_PATH /files/?.lua;;
```

However, on docker run, this returns

```
error loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'custom-plugin': custom-plugin plugin is enabled but not installed;

module 'kong.plugins.custom-plugin.handler' not found:No LuaRocks module found for kong.plugins.custom-plugin
```

I have confirmed that the files are in the correct structure, nested within the kong/plugins directory at runtime.

Can anyone help with solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check these resources out:**

- https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/installation-instructions-for-unix
- https://luarocks.org/
- https://luarocks.org/modules/seifchen/kong-path-whitelist
- https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/4696

**Bug Report from Kong:** https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/4696

```
I don't think it's the luarocks' problem
Indeed, I installed kong in docker whose image is built by a dockerfile.
In my docker file, I went into the folder which store the custom plugins,and then traverse and luarocks make them by shell.It looks like:

#install private plugins
cd APIGPlugins

for dir in `ls`; do
    if [ -d $dir ]; then
      cd $dir;
      luarocks make;
      cd ../;
    fi
done
and then, I run the docker images for a container by the directive:

sudo docker run -d --name kong \
    -e "KONG_DATABASE=off" \
    -e "KONG_DECLARATIVE_CONFIG=/etc/kong/kong.yml" \
    -e "KONG_PLUGINS=apig-response-transform" \
    -e "KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8001, 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl" \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -p 8443:8443 \
    -p 8001:8001 \
    -p 8444:8444 \
    kong-plugin:v4
As u see, I set the kong plugin by the docker run env variable parameter for enable the plugin instead of setting in the kong.conf.
The logs were generated by directive of docker logs "container ID"
It works when I tried to install another custom plugin in this way,but not work when install the custom plugin I described before
```

## Update

you need to install the lua-package manager `luarocks`

- [Documentaton Link](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/luarocks)
- [Download Link](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Download)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried running the solution as above, but the `luarocks make` line throws:  Argument missing: please specify a rockspec to use on current directory.  I'm running it in the plugins/custom-plugin directory, and I've also tried from within custom-plugin but I get the same error.

Comment: you need to install the lua-package manager `luarocks` : [Documentaton Link](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/luarocks) | [Download Link](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Download)

Comment: Answer Updated, see end of Answer.

Answer (score -1):

See if one of the instructions from [`Kong/kong-plugin-zipkin` issue 5](https://github.com/Kong/kong-plugin-zipkin/issues/5#issuecomment-396011611) (another plugin which depends on `kong.plugins.custom-plugin.handler`) would work for `kong.plugins.custom-plugin.handler` itself.

> The gist of it is that the plugin should be available to Kong on disk, and added to the custom_plugins configuration property.
>
> You can achieve this via various ways:
>
> - using Docker volumes,
> - creating your own image,
> - or even with projects or inspiration such as https://github.com/dojot/kong.
>
> Don't forget that you can also specify configure Kong with environment variables, so using `-e KONG_CUSTOM_PLUGINS=my-custom-plugin` would also work.
>
> The plugin also needs to be in the `LUA_PATH` (like PATH, but for Lua modules).
>
> So, in short, one of the possible solutions would be to use volumes and environment variables:
>
> - Mount the plugin's code: `-v /path/to/my-custom-plugin:/etc/kong/plugins/my-custom-plugin`
> - Add the directory containing custom plugins to the `LUA_PATH`: `-e KONG_LUA_PACKAGE_PATH=/etc/?.lua` (Kong requires `kong.plugins.custom-plugin.handler`, which translates to `/etc/kong/plugins/my-custom-plugin/handler.lua`)
> - Instruct Kong to load the plugin with: `-e KONG_CUSTOM_PLUGINS=my-custom-plugin`

Follwing that, check first if this is a `KONG_LUA_PATH` problem, as in [`Kong/kong` issue 3394](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/3394#issuecomment-381229579).

This was about plugin migration, but might have an impact here as well.

> as a short term solution, you should set your `LUA_PATH` environment variable to point to your custom plugin's installation path
>   (instead of `lua_package_path` in `kong.conf` or `KONG_LUA_PACKAGE_PATH`).
>
> E.g. I just moved:
>
> ```
> export KONG_LUA_PACKAGE_PATH="/path/to/some-custom-plugin/?.lua;;"
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> export LUA_PATH="/path/to/some-custom-plugin/?.lua;$LUA_PATH"
> ```
>
> And ran `kong migrations up` again, which successfully ran the plugin's migration.
>
> That is because `lua_package_path` is only for runtime Kong (within nginx), and is not being considered by the CLI (the `kong migrations` command)
>
> If I just commented the `lua_package_path` in `kong.conf` and exported `LUA_PATH` as you mentioned, it started giving me this error:
>
> ```
> ./kong:3: module 'luarocks.loader' not found:
> ```
>
> The shell from which I am executing kong migrations up never had `LUA_PATH` set, even before. It appears `luarocks` internally creates `LUA_PATH` if it is not already set in the shell.
>
> So the additional step I had to perform was to get the current `LUA_PATH` that's set internally by running "`luarocks path`" command and then take the result of that, and append my custom login plugin path to it and then export that `LUA_PATH` to get this to work.

Again, even this your current issue is not about migration, one of those variables might help.